# Is POST only way to send data in django?

Tags: django

So i am creating an application in which am showing university information to students. When the click on apply - i will be showing a modal and asking them to select "Month".

So am using "id" from the main page to get the course students selected and now i want to know the month which they selected. If its just sending "id" means i can just do `{% url 'application-save' data.id %}`

But i also need to Month from modal, so i tried that by making a form inside modal and collecting the selected ! And ya its working, i used the below

`request.POST['selected_month']`

And its perfectly saved, now my concern is this the right way ? is this secure way to do ?

How to send a data without post and passing to url ?

Comment: Yes, a POST request is normally used to create (and sometimes) delete an item. Another option is a PUT request, but you can not do that with a HTML form: one can do that for example with an AJAX request.

Comment: Ya am not creating or deleting ! I just need pass a data to my function def ! So that i can process things ! My function doesnt depends on the data coming

Comment: A GET request is a "passive" request for information. Any parameter that's necessary for that request goes into the URL. A POST request is for manipulating information, i.e. submitting new information or altering existing information. **This is important, because those requests are treated differently by browsers and intermediate infrastructure** with regards to caching, how they appear in your browser history and the like. So choose based on that first and foremost. If you have problems making an appropriate GET request in certain situations, ask more specifically about that.

Comment: @sixovov947: If I understand it correctly you are creating data in the sense that you make a record that for the given student and the given university, it will save the selected month.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, when you're talking about records that are ultimately saved in a database, `POST` is used to create, `PUT` to update, and `PATCH` to partially update. They are all just different HTTP methods that you can use to send data in the body of the message. What you're doing here by sending user input via the body of the POST message is fine, and secure (as long as the app is ultimately deployed using HTTPS). This is the intended use.

Comment: PUT is also often used to make *idempotent* changes, such that running the same request multiple times, will have the same effect as running it once.